# Which one is correct, "on my behalf" or "behalf of me"?

Tags: word-usage, nouns

Which one is correct to say or write: "on my behalf" or "behalf of me"?

Comment: Depends on the context.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following is Oxford Dictionary's definition for *behalf*:
***on behalf of sb | on sb's behalf***
 1. as the representative of sb or instead of them
- On behalf of the department I would like to thank you all. 
- Mr. Knight cannot be here, so his wife will accept the prize on his behalf.
2. in order to help sb
- They campaigned on behalf of asylum seekers.
3. because of sb; for sb
- Don't worry on my behalf
(Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary 8th Edition )

Given the definition, both of the uses mentioned in the question are acceptable.

Answer (score -2):

There are two correct ways to form this phrase:

1. *on my behalf*
2. *on behalf of me*

*on behalf of someone* is a phrase. The *of someone* part can be put between *on* and *behalf* using a determiner instead of a pronoun.

Comment: Please [edit] to include an explanation of *why* this is correct; answers without explanation do not teach the patterns of the language well.

Comment: This does not say which of the two is correct or why.